# What is the best way to pass a custom class (inherits QObject) to QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

Having used Qt for C++ applications for quite some time now I wanted to do my next project using QML.
I now have the following scenario:
[image: Pseudo UML of the projects architecture]

- *red*: QML files and QML engine
- *blue*: C++ classes

Now I want to be able to call C++ functions from my QML files (*green arrows*).

- `Content.qml` needs to read properties from WifiManager
- `LiveField.qml` and `GameField.qml` need to show / hide the corresponding C++ views

I used C++ for the views because of some heavy 3D stuff which I'm not that familiar with in QML (I only used QML for the UI menu).

I'd rather not create the C++ classes from within my QML code using `qmlRegisterType` since I need to do some initializing in my C++ code.

What is the best way to solve my problem?

Comment: Have you seen this article? Was really helpful for me: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-overview.html

Comment: "Having used Qt for C++ applications for quite some time now I wanted to do my next project using QML..." That's how conflicts start in the Middle East.

Comment: read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-bestpractices.html#interacting-with-qml-from-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ objects are typically shared using `QQmlContext::setContextProperty`. You can find more information about QQmlContext [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcontext.html). This makes any object (or value) that you put in the context widely available.

Two words of caution though:

- Use your context properties only in high-level components, and not in reusable ones, as this will create a direct dependency to these values
- Be careful to load your GUI **after** you set all your context properties, to make sure they are accessible by you UI from the start.

#### C++ side

```
#include "wifimanager.h"

// That one is required
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>   

void main() {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    WifiManager wifi;
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("wifiManager", &wifi);

    engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    return app.exec();
}
```

You can then use `wifiManager` on the QML side, along with its `slots`, `Q_PROPERTY`ies, and `signals`

#### Reading a Q_PROPERTY

As with regular QML, you can now bind and read your object's properties.

- Read: `var value = wifiManager.value`
- Bind: `someProperty: wifiManager.value`

Any QML binding will be re-evaluated automatically whenever the value changes, as long as you emit the associated `NOTIFY` signal. For example:

`Q_PROPERTY(QString ssid READ ssid WRITE setSsid NOTIFY ssidChanged)`

```
Text {
    // Calls the READ getter of your Q_PROPERTY
    // Will automatically update whenever the SSID changes
    text: wifiManager.ssid
}
```

#### Writing a Q_PROPERTY

As easy as reading the value, you can write to it by doing `wifiManager.ssid = xxx`

```
Button {
    text: "Reset SSID"
    onClicked: {
        // Calls the WRITE setter of your Q_PROPERTY
        wifiManager.ssid = ""
    }
}
```

#### Handling signals

Signals can be handled with the `Connections` object. As with any QML object, you have to prefix your signal's name with `on` and a capital letter. Which gives `onWifiConnected: {}` for signal `void wifiConnected();`

```
Connections {
    target: wifiManager
    // Handle `wifiConnected` signal
    onWifiConnected: {
        console.log("Connected!")

        // If your `wifiConnected` signal has an argument named `ip`
        // it will be available here under the same name
        console.log("My IP is", ip)
    }
}
```

#### Calling slots

Slots and `Q_INVOKABLE`s are accessible as any other functions in javascript. So you can call `wifiManager.disconnect()`

```
Button {
    text: "disconnect"
    onClicked: {
        // Calls the `disconnect` slot or Q_INVOKABLE
        wifiManager.disconnect()
    }
}
```

Comment: So even if my WifiManager should only have one instance, you still recommend contextProperty over the singleton approach? In C++ I rarely used singletons, but does QML require different? And secondly: If I use contextProperty, is every QML file able to acces e.g. WifiManager?

Comment: Using `setContextProperty` is the best approach in most situations, where you need to "inject/supply" an object to the UI. Which works perfectly well in your case, as it will let do you the initialization part you mentionned. And it is more analog to dependency injection rather than a "Singleton" approach, but I believe this is for the best, as Singleon is know for its problems for testing, code flexibility, and multithreading. Another approach would be to expose a `Repository` or `Factory` object, but I would not say it is necessary in your case.

Comment: "If I use contextProperty, is every QML file able to acces e.g. WifiManager?"
Yes!